# How to define all getters and setters at once?

Tags: java, setter, getter

One thing I find irritating when coding a Java class is the getters and setters. It quickly gets tiresome to code 2 methods for each private attribute of a class.

So, I wonder if there is a way to **define several/all getters and setters of a given class with just one statement?** I saw this is possible in some languages, but does Java support it?

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: Some IDEs have short cuts that add this code for you.

Comment: Your IDE supports it.

Comment: Move to Scala — will solve other problems as well.

Comment: While it's certainly true that some boilerplate code may be involved for setters and getters (particularly when you want to add JavaDocs...), and that it may be tiresome to create it, this has one advantage: **You will not do it blindly**. You should think **thoroughly** about whether you need a *getter* for a field, and even more whether you need a *setter*. In any case, even though IDEs offer the possibility to do so: Don't blindly click that button...

Comment: Yes, I do use Eclipse. But I didn't know it had this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not support this.  (Honestly I wish it did.)  But many IDEs will write code for you, which is very handy.  Check out the [docs for NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/editor-codereference.html#generatecode) which will write these getters and setters for you in one go.

> Press Alt-Insert (or choose Source > Insert Code) anywhere in the
>   Editor to insert a construct from the Code Generation box. The
>   suggested list is adjusted to the current context.
>
> ...In the IDE's Java Editor, you can automatically generate various
>   constructs and whole methods, override and delegate methods, add
>   properties and more.

Answer (score 6):

May I suggest project [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html)? One of its features is creating trivial default getters and setters unless you explicitly override them with your own.

Comment: +1 I have used Lombok.  It's an amazing tool.  It's great at eliminating boiler plate code.

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse, right click on the class that you want to generate for, and select source->getters and setters->and then check all the fields and select both getters and setters. This will generate them for you in bulk

For Intellij - open the class you want to generate for and then click Code ->Generate -> getters and setters.

Other IDE's have this functionality too but I only know Eclipse and Intellij off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans, right click and select insert code and then getters and setters. It will show you all the variables. tick mark the variables for which you want to create getters and setters. you can also select all fields.